# is it possible to work with the results of ActiveRecord group method directly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model `Event`, it has an attribute `ticket_id`. I'm grouping my `events` by this attribute like this:

```
Event.group(:ticket_id).having('count(events.ticket_id) > 1')
```

and it is a perfectly working query, yet I don't understand how to work with the result of such a query directly.

I understand that I, for instance, may call method `count` on it and get a hash with ticket_ids and number of corresponding events. But I need to get a structure with ticket_ids as keys and arrays of events as values like this one:

```
{ 1 => [#<Event:1>, #<Event:2>], 2 => [#<Event:3>, #<Event:4>], ... }
```

I can achieve such a result using plain ruby `group_by`, but considering the fact that I have several millions of events it seems like not the best solution. Is it possible to achieve the result somehow using ActiveRecord or probably plain SQL?

P.S. I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Considering that you have millions of events it seems unlikely to me that you want to render all events on one page groups by some attribute. What do you really want to show on that page?

Comment: I'm not going to render them. I just want to know if can get such a structure using ActiveRecord or plain SQL, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord#group` creates a SQL `GROUP BY` clause and that will always return a single list of items and not a nested data structure. Therefore the answer is: No you cannot create such a nested structure just with `ActiveRecord`

You would need to run something like `groub_by(:events_count)` on the list returned from `ActiveRecord` to translate the list into a nested structure.